# Renaming multiple files when uploaded

Tags: php, file, timestamp, rename

I have a form that uploads multiple file. The php code that I am using works fine but I would like to rename the files also and don't know how to go about this. I think adding a time stamp to the name would be the best answer. Here is the working code so far:

```
/* FILE UPLOAD CODE */
{
    $number_of_file_fields = 0;
    $number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
    $number_of_moved_files = 0;
    $uploaded_files = array();
    $upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploads/'; //set upload directory
    /**
     * we get a $_FILES['file'] array ,
     * we procee this array while iterating with simple for loop
     * you can check this array by print_r($_FILES['file']);
     */
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {
        $number_of_file_fields++;
        if ($_FILES['file']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field empty or not
            $number_of_uploaded_files++;
            $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i])) {
                $number_of_moved_files++;
            }

        }

    }

}
/* END FILE UPLOAD CODE */
```

Any help on what to add and where to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give the same name to all the uploaded files, then you can get the name by using `$_GET`.
For example:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"> \\ this would send it to your page
<input type='text' size='30' name='filename'/>
<input type='submit' /> 
</form>
```

simply get the name using `$_GET` like this

```
$name = $_GET['filename'];
```

and now run your code but move the file with this name like this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory .         $name[$i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the new file name as the second parameter in move_uploaded_file()

For example:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . "new_file_name");
```

Comment: This works but if 2 people upload a file the second overwrites the first and there is no file extention

Comment: I guess I was just showing how to give the file a different name when you move it.  But yeah, I see you still need a solution to generate a new unique name...